# Correct routing settings for NICs to use Ubuntu 16.04 as a router

Tags: networking, 16.04, routing

OK, so I'm having trouble getting this working. My home internal network is a wireless one, and what I want to do is have a small wired network on a different subnet connected to one of my Ubuntu machines. The devices on this subnet need static IP addresses so `share this connection` for my `eth0` interface won't work. Ideally this wired network will be able to connect to the internet, but it's not essential.

I've read a few guides on how to get this up and running, but there are conflicting opinions on the correct way to do it. Much of it seems to recommend using iptables but one site I was on yesterday said this was outdated (unfortunately I cannot find the link)

[image: Network topology]

Currently I have enabled ipv4 forwarding on the "pc in the middle"

```
will@will-Inspiron-7520 ~ 15:27:52 $ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

and have set up a route on one of the pcs on the wireless network to route requests for the `192.168.1.0` subnet to `10.10.10.10` (the wlan0 interface on the routing pc)

```
root@ubuntuserver will 15:29:57 # netstat -nra
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.1.0     10.10.10.10     255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 wlan0
```

I've tried several different settings for the routing in the wlan0 interface on the router pc, but nothing seems to work. I can ping a (currently the only one) device on the 192.168.1.0 subnet from the router

```
will@will-Inspiron-7520 ~ 15:27:40 $ tracepath -n 192.168.1.91
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.91                                          0.887ms reached
 1:  192.168.1.91                                          0.734ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 1
```

but trying the same thing from the wlan device results in this

```
root@ubuntuserver will 15:33:13 #  tracepath -n 192.168.1.91
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  10.10.10.10                                           3.480ms 
 1:  10.10.10.10                                           3.315ms 
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
```

the tcp dump from the router during this operation looks like this

```
root@will-Inspiron-7520 /home/will 15:33:18 # tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:33:38.497861 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44446: UDP, length 1472
15:33:39.499752 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44447: UDP, length 1472
15:33:40.487270 IP 192.168.1.250.34039 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:33:40.500022 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44448: UDP, length 1472
15:33:41.487966 IP 192.168.1.250.34039 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:33:41.502207 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44449: UDP, length 1472
15:33:42.488416 IP 192.168.1.250.34039 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:33:42.503148 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44450: UDP, length 1472
15:33:43.488986 IP 192.168.1.250.34039 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:33:43.503342 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44451: UDP, length 1472
15:33:43.503741 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.91 tell 192.168.1.250, length 28
15:33:43.504546 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.91 is-at 00:80:45:55:12:e8 (oui Unknown), length 46
15:33:44.258714 IP 192.168.1.250.17500 > 192.168.1.255.17500: UDP, length 177
15:33:44.523228 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44452: UDP, length 1472
15:33:45.547240 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44453: UDP, length 1472
15:33:46.571280 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44454: UDP, length 1472
15:33:47.540967 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44455: UDP, length 1472
15:33:48.523486 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.59424 > 192.168.1.91.44456: UDP, length 1472
^C
18 packets captured
18 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

the routing table on the router looks like this

```
root@will-Inspiron-7520 /home/will 15:33:49 # netstat -nra
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I can't get 192.168.1.250 to go in as the gateway through the gui but when I run `sudo route delete -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 0.0.0.0 && sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.250` my routing table changes to this

```
root@will-Inspiron-7520 /home/will 15:37:33 # netstat -nra
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.250   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Which in turn changes the `tcpdump` to this

```
root@will-Inspiron-7520 /home/will 15:39:35 # tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:39:40.490804 IP 192.168.1.250.46819 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:39:40.553050 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44446: UDP, length 1472
15:39:41.491671 IP 192.168.1.250.46819 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:39:41.554906 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44447: UDP, length 1472
15:39:42.492371 IP 192.168.1.250.46819 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:39:42.555628 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44448: UDP, length 1472
15:39:43.493366 IP 192.168.1.250.46819 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 171
15:39:43.557677 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44449: UDP, length 1472
15:39:44.365950 IP 192.168.1.250.17500 > 192.168.1.255.17500: UDP, length 177
15:39:44.659103 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44450: UDP, length 1472
15:39:45.581510 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44451: UDP, length 1472
15:39:46.605286 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44452: UDP, length 1472
15:39:47.628312 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44453: UDP, length 1472
15:39:48.652259 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44454: UDP, length 1472
15:39:49.697026 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44455: UDP, length 1472
15:39:50.599268 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44456: UDP, length 1472
15:39:51.622447 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44457: UDP, length 1472
15:39:52.563705 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44458: UDP, length 1472
15:39:53.669767 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44459: UDP, length 1472
15:39:54.594106 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44460: UDP, length 1472
15:39:55.616774 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44461: UDP, length 1472
15:39:56.640204 IP ubuntuserver.ftb.33901 > 192.168.1.91.44462: UDP, length 1472
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? As I said, it isn't essential that the 192.168.1.0 network can reach the internet (though it would be desirable) but the minimum would be the 10.10.10.0 subnet being able to see the 192.168.1.0 devices.

Comment: Why are you adding an interface of the router as a (remote) gateway `sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.250` ?  The router already knows how to reach `192.168.1.0` as directly attached on interface `eth0`.  Is `iptables` or any other packet filter running on the router at all?

Comment: I tried it with and without a routing entry, is it not needed then? I haven't done anything with iptables directly. Ufw is running but I've tried disabling it while running tests to make sure it wasn't interfering with anything with the intentions of opening up the relevant ports when I need them

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm an idiot. I didn't have the gateway set up properly on the 192.168.1.x machine. It was still set up as 192.168.1.1 (which doesn't exist)

Once I changed this I can now ping both ways. And I have internet access on the 192.x.x.x network.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Step: If you want to add wired equipment to your internal network, you must add a network card (eth1) and a switch of at least 5-8 ports.

2.- Install DHCP Server and make IP reservations for wired computers.

3.- Execute IPTables

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -F
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain


iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT

modprobe ip_conntrack
modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Internet for Wireless 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.X/X -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
# Internet for Wired
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.X/X -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

You very well may have this setup correctly and this may have something to do with the wireless interface you're using. Typically the way to do something like this is with a dedicated wireless access point you connect to a controller(in this case your server) via Ethernet. check out ubnt.com they have some good relatively cheap ones.

Comment: I understand there is dedicated hardware to do what I want, but I'd like to utilise the hardware I already have. There are a multitude of guides online to use Ubuntu (or other distributions) as a router but I'm clearly missing something as it just doesn't want to work properly. I can't decipher the output of `tcpdump` but it looks like the packet is getting as far as "the router". For clarity here, `ubuntuserver.ftb ` is actually the client in this setup. `will-Inspiron-7520` is the router and 192.168.1.91 is the only device on the second subnet

Comment: Exactly. My theory was that its only making it to "the router" because the wireless card in the will-Inspiron-7520 doesn't have support for what you are trying to do. I only say this because I tried something similar a while back and ran into this limitation. If you are able to plug into the 10.0.0.0\24 with an Ethernet cable and use that interface you should have better luck. Basically with most wireless cards you cant be connected as a client to the network you are trying to route to. There just isnt enough interfaces. You would have to use one to send and one to recieve. Hope that helps

Comment: I'm connected to eth0  . Maybe I wasn't clear. The 192.x.x.x network is hard wired , the 10.x.x.x network is wifi.  In any case I'm working now, it was an error on my part with the client on the 192.x.x.x network.